# Memory errors in array resize

Tags: c++, heap

So I'm trying to make a template class for a heap. I'm trying not to use any of the STL classes (professor's rules and whatnot) so rather than use a vector I use a dynamically allocated array. However, when I run the program and input enough data into the heap for it to trigger the resizing function, it springs a bunch of memory errors. Some gdb work narrowed it down to this function:

```
template <class T>
T* Heap<T>::resize()
{
    T* temp; //temp variable for storage

    heap_capacity *= 2; //double capacity
    temp = new T[heap_capacity]; //create new enlarged array
    for (int i = 0; i < heap_size; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = heap_arr[i]; //copy elements from previous array to current
    }
    delete [] heap_arr; //delete old array
    return temp; //return new array
}
```

Pretty standard stuff, tbh. It requires whatever T is to have an assignment operator, but I was testing it using plain old integers. This isn't the first time I've written this code, but it is the first time I've written it for a template. Does the problem lie in this function, or is it somewhere else?

Edit: I played around with the code a little bit more in gdb. Turns out the program errors out right after I allocate memory for temp. This is strange, because I do the same thing for the original heap_array in the constructor. I'll be poking around a bit more, but is my syntax wrong for the "new" statement? heap_capacity is valid, btw, so that's not the problem...

Comment: Probably heap_size is bigger than heap_capacity.

Comment: What are the specific errors you get?

Comment: I recommend you to firstly write your (minimal) clone of `std::vector`, debug it with many test cases, and then write a heap class on top of it.  This is because your bug is more related to "program design" than to "algorithm and data structure" class which you attend.  You should have caught the bug in your `resize()` method (without `size` parameter!) if you followed this approach.

Comment: @Barmar It's really hard to read through a memory map error...

Comment: The function only starts when heap_size is equal to heap_capacity. And I double heap capacity before using new. I have no idea how the heap_size could be bigger than the heap capacity if this the condition must be met. This is in a testing program solely with pushes.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you need to set `heap_arr` to point to the new expanded memory. It would certainly make sense for the `resize` method to take care of this:

```
delete [] heap_arr;
heap_arr = temp;
return heap_arr;
```

You also need to be sure that the `heap_size` is less than `heap_capacity`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've figured out why I was getting the error. Turns out my check to see if the size of the heap was equal to the capacity forgot a crucial part: the extra 0 at the top of the array. The heap is 1-based (as opposed to 0-based) so the fix was simple: change the `heap_size == heap_capacity` statement to `heap_size == heap_capacity-1`... an important distinction. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Don't you also need the fix in juanchopanza's answer?

Comment: It wasn't absolutely necessary, but I did implement a slightly modified version of the fix, yes.